# How to ignore "name XXX already exists" messages when moving sheets in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy from one workbook to another but get a message as I move the sheet that a name already exists.  is there a way to automatically ignore this message?

The message is:
[image] is:

the code for the copy

```
CurrentWorkBook.Sheets(Array("Compliance - learning")).Copy Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    CurrentWorkBook.Sheets(Array("Compliance - learning")).Copy Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Thanks- works perfectly, I will tick this as soon as I can!

Comment: @PartyHatPanda how to use this code?

Comment: The Application.DisplayAlerts = false in a vba macro suppresses the pop up window(s) during a running macro. Add the code to wherever you want to hide pop-ups. Just make sure to turn it back on when you are done.